# xsl:template to display variable value

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to display variable value (value is good) into a template

This variable works :

```html
<xsl:variable name="nomUpper" select="concat(translate(substring(nom/text(),1,1), $smallcase, $uppercase),
          substring(nom/text(), 2),
          substring(' ', 1 div not(position()=last()))
         )" />
```

This code works (into xsl:for-each) :

```html
 <h2><xsl:number format="1. " /><xsl:value-of select="$nomUpper" />
                 </h2>
```

But I must use a template to display $nomUpper value

Could you help me to find how ?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: I must use xsl:template to display the var but i don't know how

Comment: Repeating the same thing does not help. See the help on how to ask - esp. this: [mcve].